# Angular 8: How to patch formcontrol values to mat-datepicker with [min] date validation and formcontrol date value is less then the [min] Date?

Tags: angular, date, angular-reactive-forms, mat-datepicker

How to patch formcontrol values to mat-datepicker with [min] Date validation and formcontrol date is less then the [min] Date?

here is the `html`.

```html
<label class="label input-form-label">Date:</label>
<span class="input-group-addon" (click)="picker.open();">
  <input [matDatepicker]="picker" [min]="today" type="text" class="input-form" formControlName="date">
  <div class="datepicker-icon-div" style="right: 30px;">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </div>
</span>
<span>
  <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</span>
```

here is the `reactive form`.

```js
today = new Date(); // suppose todays date is 27-05-2020 
pastDate = new Date(2020, 05, 24);

this.form = this.fb.group({
  date: [this.today, Validators.required]
})

patchFormValue(){
  this.form.patchValue({
    date: this.pastDate
  })
}
```

I want to disable the past dates from the `matdatepicker` so i have added the [min] validation to it. But i want to patch past date too.
Is there any other way so that i can disable the dates or patch the past date?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you still need this or not, but I ran into something similar today where we had values coming from a db that were older than todays date, but we didn't allow them to pick dates from the picker that were older dates.

I ended up doing something that worked for me though it isn't pretty.

First I added a [dateClass]="dateClass()" and [startAt]="today" to the Date Picker and got rid of the [min] validation.

```html
<label class="label input-form-label">Date:</label>
<span class="input-group-addon" (click)="picker.open();">
  <input [matDatepicker]="picker" type="text" class="input-form" formControlName="date">
  <div class="datepicker-icon-div" style="right: 30px;">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
  </div>
</span>
<span>
  <mat-datepicker [startAt]="today" [dateClass]="dateClass()" #picker></mat-datepicker>
</span>
```

Then I added that method to the component.ts so that it would add a new css style to all values that were before todays date.

```js
dateClass() {
    return (date: Date): MatCalendarCellCssClasses => {
        return  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) < this.today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) ? 'disable-dates' : undefined;
    }
}
```

Then I added that css class to my component so it would mock the style of mat disabled dates from the date picker

```css
::ng-deep.disable-dates {
  pointer-events: none;
}

::ng-deep.disable-dates > .mat-calendar-body-cell-content {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
}
```

This way it would disable the dates in the datepicker but would not cause that validation to happen on the input field the picker was attached to.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-atw9cz

Answer (score 0):

**In Js Month is zero indexed so May == 4**

Refer

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aeasyj